# Superdry Color Picker not rendering on ICS correctly

Tags: android, color-picker

I found that when I set my targetSDK to 15 that I get the color wheel in this app not rendering the colors correctly as per the issue I raised below.

http://code.google.com/p/superdry-colorpicker/issues/detail?id=2

Having not heard back from the developer yet I want to try and fix it myself, but I am completely lost when I look at the code.

Is someone albe to tell me what the issue is or point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably due to ICS hardware acceleration that gets enabled when you set it to that target version. Try to disable HW acceleration and see if that works for your app (in your manifest)

Comment: <application android:hardwareAccelerated="false" ...> worked!  Thank you so much :)